# boost MPI example valgrind output

Tags: boost, mpi, valgrind

I am trying to use this (http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.mpi-simple-data-exchange#ex.mpi_01) example 47.2 to understand the valgrind outputs for my own boost mpi code ran with valgrind. This following code ran fine and I got "99" back. However, when I ran it with valgrind, I got "Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)" complaints.

```
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  boost::mpi::environment env{argc, argv};
  boost::mpi::communicator world;
  if (world.rank() == 0)
  {
    int i;
    world.recv(1, 16, i);
    std::cout << i << '\n';
  }
  else if (world.rank() == 1)
  {
    world.send(0, 16, 99);
  }
}

Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
at 0x37BEA0E6FD: ??? (in /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so)
.......
by 0x409B70: main (e47.2.cpp:6)
Address 0x7feffec48 is on thread 1's stack
.......
```

Comment: You did not mention what MPI library you were used. Some MPI libraries are known to be not Valgrind clean. For example OpenMPI FAQ contains an entry saying that the library may write to uninitialized memory. In that case, one can use so-called suppression file to stop Valgrind from warning.

Comment: @macelee Boost MPI library.  Thanks a lot, I understand it now.